# Libgdx Game crashes when using Box2d World

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I created a libgdx game that works fine on desktop mode, then I tried it to run on android platform. The game goes to the menu screen without any problem but when I click the play button, the game closes "Unfortunately, mygame stopped working".

I have a loding screen and when it's done loading the assets it goes to the menu screen:

```
if(assetManager.update()){
            game.setScreen(new MenuScreen(game, assetManager));
        }
```

Then on my menu screen I have a play button that when clicked it goes to the game screen:

```
ChangeListener listener = new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {

                //play button
                if(actor.equals(playBtn)) {
                    menuMusic.stop();
                    game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game, assetManager, settingsPrefs));
                }
           }
     }
```

On desktop mode it works fine but on Android once I click the play button I get these errors (not the full log):

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 4474
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myname.mygame.worlds.MyContactListener
E/AndroidGraphics: waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing
```

The error log says that the problem is is the box2d world and it's contact listener, but to me it's all good. I'm thinking it's the `ParticleEffect` I have quite a few of them and I did not load them properly I just used the `Gdx.files.internal()`. How do you load Libgdx ParticleEffect on AssetManager?

is there a way for the application to not assume deadlock? so that the application does not close

**UPDATE (I found what causes the error)**

So I tried to change my code cause I taught the way I coded the game is not that good and still have the same problem on the Android platform. The game run properly and it goes to the menu screen but when you click the play button it crashes. So what I did is added a Box2d world in the menu screen

```
world = new World(0f, -10f);
```

Then I got the same error when I try to transition to the game screen

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 8739
        Process: com.myname.mygame, PID: 12794
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World;
```

Once I added box2d world to the class I just get the error, the problem is on the World class, so how do I know if the package which contains the class is properly installed? or there are other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

As the documention says:
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World.html,

World has only this constructor

`World(Vector2 gravity, boolean doSleep)`

So how is it possible that you are creating a World object in that way?

Furthemore, check this answer :

http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=22311